# Symmetric polynomials; $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\in\Bbb{C}$ s.t. $\prod_{i=0}^n\left(a_i^k+1\right)=1,\;\forall k\in\Bbb{N}\implies a_1=\dots =a_n=0$

Tags: complex-numbers, symmetric-polynomials

> Let $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\in\Bbb{C}$ s.t. $\prod_\limits{i=0}^n\left(a_i^k+1\right)=1,\;\forall k\in\Bbb{N}$.
>
> Prove that $a_1=a_2=\dots=a_n=0$.

I have tried to show that all symmetric elementary polynomials determined by $a_{1},a_{2}\dots a_{n}$ are equal to $0$. My guess is that I have to expand, and use *Newton sums* to express the L.H.S in terms of the symmetric elementary polynomials, but the equations don't look very nice.

Comment: Have you tried to look at $\mathbb C_{\mathbb R}\cong\mathbb R^2$ and take $\{\alpha_i, a_1\}$ as a basis for $\mathbb C_{\mathbb R}$?